# Redirect 301 in Nginx (images and dynamic pages)

Tags: image, redirect, dynamic, nginx

I am changing my site address and I am having difficulty in two types of 301 redirects on the server Nginx. I've tried MANY ways to do this, but everything went wrong so far.

I want to change the:

```
^/downs/pafiledb.php?action=download&id=(NUMBER)
```

to other site:

```
http://www.newsite.com/downloads/NUMBER
```

And also a problem with the redirect with the pictures, see below.

I want to change the entire folder to another site:

```
^/images/
```

to

```
http://www.newsite.com/images/
```

How can I do this? I've tried every way possible in Nginx and nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location = /downs/pafiledb.php {
    if ($arg_action = download) {
        return 301 http://www.newsite.com/downloads/$arg_id;
    }
}

location /images/ {
    return 301 http://www.newsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- http://nginx.org/r/if
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html